# New to Android development and while following tutorial by teamtreehouse, I keep getting errors

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, adt

[tutorial link](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-android-app/getting-started-with-android/android-setup-and-the-crystal-ball-project-2)

So I pick from apk 8 through current one kitkat.

I create application/project,

```
The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar is never used.
The import android.os.Build is never used.
```

and then I get the above errors from the MainActivity.java file regarding these two lines:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Build;
```

And the graphical view of `activity_main.xml` shows no "Hello world!" text, and it sends me to the `fragment_main.xml` where the "Hello world!" text is on the top left.

I'm pretty sure the tutorial I'm following is a bit outdated since it didn't show fragment xml and kitkat version. So was this all normal?

Comment: It's just telling you that those `import`s aren't necessary; you can delete them. Are you unable to compile and run the project?

Comment: Yes I was able to compile and run it, but the view came up in my nexus 5 as fragment, and not the main. Shouldn't it be running the main &/or should I just be using an android emulator for simplicity sakes. Connecting my android phone was a pain/hassle

Comment: It is; the Fragment is contained within the main Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. it is safe to remove any imports not bieng used, so delete those....

as for the activity, you can create an activity without fragments by selecting blank activity from the creation wizard.(one of the options, after u select new android project)

really though, you should find a good fragment tutorial as that is the direction apps are headed, and once you understand them they make life a lot easier

Comment: I think you mean "remove any _imports_".

Answer (score 1):

im not sure about teamtreehouse tutorials, but i've been experienceng troubles with android sample projects that you can get from developer.google.com.

Anyhow, in my experince.. I was able to fix it. I'm hoping u are using android studio, do update first! Then once you impirort thpe project do few more things..

1. update your android studio.on mac it would be AndoidStudio->Check for updates..
2. Make sure your app build.gradle (NOT PRoject build.Gradle!!!!!) has this

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
   }
3. Make sure you installed the lates android SDK!!! Today it sooul be 19.0.3
   then in the same buid.gradle make sure you have

android {
    ...
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
    ...
}

3. project-root/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. The distributionUrl property is where you set the Gradle version; it's embedded in the URL:

distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip

The latest gradle is 1.11 as today...

Final step -> File-> Invalidate cashes/Restart.

After that it should compile everything over again and it should not complain anymore..
I spent last 3 days figuring this out, Hoping it will help u as well.

Good luck